# Map a PHP array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, built-in

I would like to map PHP array values with another map. I mean something like this:

```
<?php

  function as_function($array) {
    return fn ($x) => $array[$x];
  }

  $x = array('a', 'b');
  $y = array('a' => 3, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 7);

  print_r(array_map(as_function($y), $x));
```

This code finishes with an expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
)
```

I wonder if there is some smarter way to do it by replacing `array_map(as_function` with some PHP builtin function?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not sure why that is an unexpected result or what the expected result is.

Comment: I am confused to the question, `as_function()` is unnecessary here, you can directly use `array_map(fn ($x) => $y[$x], $x)`. Are you asking if there is a in-built function in PHP to change the key value? If so, no.

Comment: Am I correct you want the values from `$y` where the keys are in `$x`?

Comment: @Michel yes. This is want I want.

I presented one way to do it. But I wonder if there is a better way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simple foreach?

```
foreach($x as $k => $v){
   $x[$k] = $y[$v];
}

print_r($x);
```

[-> Working example.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30d13f4d5014471d3843145f30b131094581c59a)

Or you could use `array_filter()` and then `array_values()` but... tbh... that depends if you want a nice solution or a short solution. The one I presented is the shortest you can get, and probably the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

it is funny but you could try this for similar result.

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($y,array_flip($x)));
```